# called async function from state is not waiting (react)

Tags: reactjs

I call a state function in my component, the function should change the state(and it does but late), i want to log the change but the log triggers before the state is changed
this is the function in the state:

```
const login = async (user, password) => {
    const body = {
      username: user,
      password: password,
    };
    await axios
      .post('/sessions', body, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: resp.data.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      });
  };
```

and this is the call in the component

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(user, password);
    console.log(credes);
  };
```

"credes" is the state for that response, but it keeps printing the initial state witch is an empty object
the function triggers on the form submission but logs first and updates the state later.

Comment: It is because `login` is an async function. Maybe you can do `login(user, password).then(() => console.log(credes))`.

Comment: why are using await and .then?

Comment: Quick thing to note: dispatch if using redux is also an async function. Printing state right after calling dispatch will not print the updated state in most cases. make sure to await that as well.

Comment: bubulledu93 you are right doing that makes the log wait and as ronakvp  pointed it stills print the original state, I'm no using redux tho I'm using useReducerhook.
-im a graphic designer trying to get into dev, some concepts are still hard to grasp

Comment: yesh, even userEReducerHook which is a hook internal to react will also be an async operation

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by bubulledu93, ronakvp and coreyward, I was butchering the syntax. I was trying to perform two actions in one function, so I moved the log into a useEffect to watch for changes in the "credes" hope is the right way but is working as I needed it.

```
  const login = (user, password) => {
    const body = {
      username: user,
      password: password,
    };
    axios
      .post('/sessions', body, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: resp.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      });
  };
```

and the call in the component + the useEffect

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(user, password);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (credes.success) {
      console.log(credes.data);
    }
  }, [credes]);
```

Comment: What you have here is exactly what you need. Another thing that you should be careful of is not to change the state of object inside useEffect on which the useEffect block is dependent upon. It will enter a recursive infinite loop. 
Just making sure that you understood that since you mentioned that you are starting out new in dev. All the best with you journey, it is rewarding.

Comment: For what it’s worth, your `useEffect` hook won’t be run until after the component re-renders and any updates have been propagated to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any benefit to `await`ing as the last call in a function. Instead of using `async` and `await`, simply return the Promise chain started by `axios.post()` to `onSubmit` and then chain on it (or use `await` there):

```js
  const login = (user, password) => {
    const body = {
      username: user,
      password: password,
    };
    return axios
      .post('/sessions', body, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: resp.data.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      });
  };

  // Option 1:
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(user, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(credes);
      });
  };

  // Option 2:
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await login(user, password);
    console.log(credes)
  }
```

Comment: it worked, now is firing the log at the proper time, yet still brings the original state, i was trying to call the function plain in the .then like this .then(console.log(credes)); without the function, now i have to figure how to detect the change in the state.

Comment: @Arturo I don't follow at all what you're trying to do. Do you just want access to the up-to-date state after you run `login`? If so, just return `resp.data.data` it after you run `dispatch()`, then you can do `const returnValue = await login(user, password)` in `onSubmit`.

Comment: yeah! that was it! i solved it with useEffect, but ill try your way too thanks!